# Reack Hook: useEffect() is called twice firt witha n empty array and then with the vales from the database

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, use-effect

I am trying to load the theme (array of colors) saved by the user but the close shows that three null values and then on the second call three color codes are loading. I am not able to fill the input controls with the values on the GET request.

HANDLER Function

```
 const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const broker = useSelector(getBrokerInformation);
    const colorlist = useSelector(getTheme);
    let code = { brokerage_code : broker.information.brokerages[0].code };
    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(getCurrentTheme(code));
    }, []);
    console.log(colorlist[0] ? colorlist[0].theme.color1 : null);
    console.log(colorlist[0] ? colorlist[0].theme.color2 : null);
    console.log(colorlist[0] ? colorlist[0].theme.color3 : null);
    const[colors, setColors] = useState({
        color1: colorlist[0] ? colorlist[0].theme.color1 : null,
        color2: colorlist[0] ? colorlist[0].theme.color2 : null,
        color3: colorlist[0] ? colorlist[0].theme.color3 : null
    });
```

INPUT Control

```
<input 
    type="text" 
    className="form-control" 
    placeholder="Enter hexcode"
    value={colors.color2} 
    onChange={(event) => { setColors({...colors, color2: event.target.value});}} />
```

REDUCER

```
const slice = createSlice({
  name: "logoandcolor",
  initialState: {
    currentTheme: []
  },
  reducers: {
    themeReceiving: (logoandcolor, action) => {
      logoandcolor.currentTheme = [];
    },
    themeReceived: (logoandcolor, action) => {
      logoandcolor.currentTheme = action.payload;
    },
    themeRetrievalFailed: (logoandcolor, action) => {
      logoandcolor.currentTheme = [];
    },
  },
});

export const {
  themeReceiving,
  themeReceived,
  themeRetrievalFailed,
} = slice.actions;

export default slice.reducer;

// GET USER THEME   
export const getCurrentTheme = (data) =>
  apiCallBegan({
    serviceUrl: process.env.REACT_APP_BASICSERVICE,
    url: "api/logoandcolor/",
    method: "post",
    data: data,
    onStart: themeReceiving.type,
    onSuccess: themeReceived.type,
    onError: themeRetrievalFailed.type,
  });

export const getTheme = createSelector(
    (state) => state.entities.logoandcolor,
    (logoandcolor) => logoandcolor.currentTheme,
  );
```

[image]

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

you need to add `dispatch` to useEffect hook like this.

```
useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getCurrentTheme(code));
}, [dispatch]);
```

Comment: This does not work, it still throws the same issue. It has to do somthing with const colorlist = useSelector(getTheme); not being able to get the state on the first call.